# Prove that $e^x>x(x+1)$

Tags: inequality

> Let $x>0$,prove that $$e^x>x(x+1)$$or
>   $$x>\ln{x}+\ln{(x+1)}$$

we can use this Taylor some  first four term,
$$e^x>1+x+\dfrac{1}{2}x^2+\dfrac{1}{6}x^3$$ prove it

But this inequality it seem very nice,maybe there exsit simple methods or Amazing way?

Comment: Isn't the method by Taylor's theorem simple?

Answer (score 4):

We need to prove$$e^x>1+x+\dfrac{1}{2}x^2+\dfrac{1}{6}x^3\ge x^2+x$$which is$$x^3+3x^2+6x+6\ge 6x^2+6x$$which is$$x^3-3x^2+6=(x-2)^2(x+1)+2>0$$which is obvious for positive $x$.

Comment: have other methods?

Comment: This is the simplest method I can think of...

Answer (score 3):

Yes. 
Let $$f(x)=e^x-x^2-x$$

And $f(0)=1$

Now, $f^{'}(x)=e^x-(2x+1)$ and $f^{"}(x)=e^x-2$
  We get local minima in $x \in (1,2) $ where $f(x)>0$.

Now Since  at minima, $f(x)>0$

Thus we can conclude $$e^x-(x^2+x)>0$$
$$e^x>(x^2+x)$$

Comment: why $f(x)>0$ when $x\in (1,2)?$

Comment: @function you may check for yourself? Or use Wolfram?

Comment: No,I hope can use hand to prove it,without wolfam

Comment: Let $0<x_0$ with $f'(x_0)=0$. Then $ e^{x_0}=1+2x_0\implies$ $f(x_0)=(1+2x_0)-x_0-x_0^2=1+x_0-x_0^2.$... The quadratic $g(x)=1+x-x^2$ is positive for   $0\leq x<(1+\sqrt 5\;)/2=1.618....,$  and we can calculate that  $f'(1.6)>0.$ So $x_0<1.6$ and $f(x_0)=g(x_0)>0.$